# Android show and edit HTML

Tags: java, android, html, android-layout

I'm working on email client and I need to show HTML email and edit it in some kind of `EditText` view.

I download email as HTML and show it in the `WebView` - it's ok. But when I want to reply to this email or edit my signature which is in HTML I need to show it in some kind of `EditText` which can show it properly and edit it.. Some kind of WYSIWYG..

Is there any solution? Thank you

Am I missing something?

EDIT: 
So I tried to use ImageGetter like this:

```
mEmailEditText.setText(Html.fromHtml(mArgumentEmail.getmHtmlMessage(), getImageHTML(), null));

private Html.ImageGetter getImageHTML() {
    Html.ImageGetter imageGetter = new Html.ImageGetter() {
        public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
            try {
                Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(new URL(source).openStream(), "src name");
                drawable.setBounds(0, 0, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
                return drawable;
            } catch(IOException exception) {
                Log.v("IOException", exception.getMessage());
                return null;
            }
        }
    };
    return imageGetter;
}
```

But it didn't work.. "Unfortunately, email has stopped." on the line `mEmailEditText.setText..`

```
 Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException ....
```

EDIT2: 
So my final working result looks like this:

```
 public Html.ImageGetter getImageHTML() {
    Html.ImageGetter imageGetter = new Html.ImageGetter() {
        public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
            DownloadImageTask task = new DownloadImageTask();
            try {
                return task.execute(new String[] { source }).get();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    };
    return imageGetter;
}

private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Drawable> {
    protected Drawable doInBackground(String... urls) {
        for(String s : urls) {
            try {
                Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(new URL(s).openStream(), "src name");
                drawable.setBounds(0, 0, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
                return drawable;
            } catch (IOException exception) {
                Log.v("IOException", exception.getMessage());
                return null;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Drawable drawable) {
        super.onPostExecute(drawable);
    }
}
```

It's working besides the email doesn't look the same as in WebView.. What's worse when I want to sent this email the email doesn't look as before.

```
Spanned html = Html.fromHtml(..);
email.setmHtmlMessage(Html.toHtml(html));
```

Is there any solution to fix it and make it look as before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the html a spanned string using `Html.fromHtml(htmldata)` and set this to the edittext.

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't show images in email.. And when I want to get this HTML reply text back from EditText and send it I don't receive formatted HTML email but just unformatted text from EditText..

Comment: it wont handle image itself we have to pass a Html.ImageGetter that i will show the image. use `fromHtml(String source, Html.ImageGetter imageGetter, Html.TagHandler tagHandler)` and pass the imagegetter that will dispaly the image.

Answer (score 1):

`getImageHTML` Needs to be run on a separate thread. There are a number of ways you can do this. For this particular task, I recommend using an `AsyncTask` since you'll be updating a UI component.

Also, `setText` should be in the `AsyncTask`'s `onPostExecute`.